# VBA to read dimensions of Images from a list of webpages

Tags: vba, excel, metadata

**My Goal:**
I have a list of 14K URLs in a column in a worksheet.
Each of those URLs have an image in them. Something like a site banner.
I want to retrieve each of those banner image's dimensions into another column in the same sheet.

Can someone tell me if this is even possible in Excel VBA.

I have tried some things but all that is like beating around the bush and not straight forward.

I have tried to get the image's URLS . Then download those URLS to the HDD using ['URLDownloadToFile'](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_download_url_to_file.html). Then I get run some more code to get the dimensions.

### **Update: Sep/15/2014 04:10 PM EST**

This is what I did:
I use this code in sheet 1 to load the URLs (from column A) and retrieve banner image URLs in column B

```
Private Sub GetEm_Click()
Dim ImageURL
Dim PageURL

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True

For RowIndex = 0 To 15000
    pURL = Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value

    On Error Resume Next
    IE.Navigate pURL

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set Doc = IE.document

    URL = Doc.getElementsByTagName("img")(1).src
    Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Select       'I select and then populate the result value so that i can see the rows scrolling. This will give me an idea that the macro is still running.
        Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Value = URL
Next i
IE.Quit
End Sub
```

**The problem with this above code is that after around 150 rows, IE stops responding and my code hangs.**

If this works, my plan then is to download the images using the image URLs from column B:
For this, as stated earlier I use:
['URLDownloadToFile'](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_download_url_to_file.html)

Then once I have downloaded them, I run a vb script to get their dimensions.

I am hoping there is a better straight forward way of doing this.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and describe the specific problems you have had using that approach. FWIW, that would probably be the first thing I try: download the files, then get their dimensions.

Comment: Does the code still hang if you make the loop shorter and break it up into several loops or if you add `Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)` and add `Sleep #` to your loop?

Comment: Looping in short chunks of data doesn't help. The memory usage on iexplore.exe in task manager keeps increasing and stops responding when it reaches a little over 1000 MBs.

The Sleep did not help either.
Thanks however.

Comment: You can try getting the HTML of the page and storing it in a string and then parsing the string for img tags. That should solve the memory problem and prevent freezing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (you'll have to change it to do specifically what you want):

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Sub GetImgData()
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim i As Long

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        URLDownloadToFile 0, Cells(i, 1).Value, "C:\temp.jpg", 0, 0

        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("C:\")
        Set objFile = objFolder.ParseName("temp.jpg")

        MsgBox objFile.ExtendedProperty("Dimensions")
        Kill "C:\temp.jpg"
    Next
End Sub
```

Some important things to note though are:

1. If the URL is invalid or does not exist the file will not be created and no error will be thrown.
2. If the file could not be downloaded the temp file will not be created so the `MsgBox` line will throw an error.
3. You may need to parse the URL for the file type. I don't know what will happen if you download a .gif as a .jpg.
4. The output of objFile.ExtendedProperty is a bit odd and will likely need to be cleaned a little. (contains ?'s)

Comment: Thanks! Your resolution partially resolve the issue I was having.
You gave a very easy way of getting the dimensions of the images that I load using their URLs.
However, the first part of my problem is actually getting all those image's URL itself.
I am having problems with that too.

Thank you very much for the answer though. It does help me to an extent.